# PCB trace width

Tags: pcb, altium, electrical, tracking

I am trying  to design a PCB circuit in altium designer.

My circuit consists of one ATmega8a, one NRF24l01 and three magnetic relays (mini relay 12V MPR-S-112-A.)

I want to set the trace width to 0.5mm (except power circuit.)

Is that correct ?

If it is wrong, what width should I use?

[image: circuit]

Comment: Saturn PCB has a handy tool for all sorts of (these things) [Link](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.5mm is 20mil, right? 
That's fine for most work at lowish frequencies.

Comment: I know this is an old post. But 20mil is NOT 0.5mm. It's 0.508mm. Not a big deal for trace width, maybe. But a real big deal for a 100 pin tqfp with 0.5mm pitch. The error across 25 pins accumulates to 0.2mm. I have just been burned by this - The engineer who created the footprint worked in Imperial units, and also used 20mil=0.5mm

Comment: @StephenCasey If you try putting 0.5mm -- or 20mil -- *width* traces into a 0.5mm *pitch* footprint, it won't exactly matter... neither one is going to connect to *any* of the pads!

Comment: He has specifically asked for tracewidth, and not a pad layout. Yes, 20mil = 0.508mm. And no - there's no "100 pin tqfp" in the schematic shown

Answer (score 1):

you can use these guidelines [Guidelines](https://www.eurocircuits.com/pcb-design-guidelines/#trackwidthgraphic) or similar as a reference for a decent layout. 
On the right hand side of the GUI, you will find track width graphic.